# Best practice to access attributes in relations belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know which is the best way to access attributes in relations of type belongs_to in my views. Let me explain, through this example:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

So, if I want to access the Author name in a view that renders all books I would do something like this:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <%= book.author.name %>
<% end %>
```

So, the output of my console is:

```
CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

So, if I had 100 books, this query will be repeated 100 times, for each book.

Is there any other way get the name of Author except by access the relation?

Save the author name in the Book table could be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called N+1 problem. The solution in your case is simple - ActiveRecord provides `includes` method, which handles fetching associated records in elegant way:

```
@books = Book.your_possible_scope.includes(:author)
```

You'll find more info on this subject in Rails Guides:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Well thank you sir. Thats exactly what I was looking for!